# Facebook GraphAPI; posting to group vs page of same name

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's GraphAPI I am trying to post to a public group. It appears that a page by the same name also exists and it is defaulting to post to that instead.

Currently I am using

```
posts = graph.get("NAME_OF_GROUP/feed", page=True, limit=1):
```

Hopefully there is a way to default it to group over page. I cannot find much in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only pages have a name that they are accessible by via API. A group name is "just for people", for display purposes, it was never possible to use that to access the group in API calls. So there is no defaulting of page over group going on here; if the page did not exist at all, you would still not be able to access the group this way - the group ID is the only way to do that.

And posting to a group will require an access token from the group admin these days, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed#publish

Comment: Thank you! I just found out that you can use this site to find the group ID from URL http://lookup-id.com/ That worked for me